# XPath match tags with case insentitive

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a feed XML and I want to select `items` in the file.

```xml
<xml>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
</xml>
```

But the user can pass the tag name like `<Item>` or `<ITEM>` or something like that. How can I write an XPath to select the items with case insentitive?

Comment: It might be better to first do a transformation step with e.g. XSLT or XQuery that normalizes the case of letters in element names before you start processing with XPath as otherwise you get rather long and potentially inefficient expressions that have to `lower-case` or (in XPath 1.0) `translate` each name

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Utilizing XPath 2.0 `lower-case` string function:

```
//*[lower-case(name())='item']
```

2. With `matches()` XPATH 2.0 function
   One of the `matches()` function flags is `i` for case-insensitive matching.

```
//*[matches(name(),'item','i')]
```

**UPD**
I do not know about real case-insensitive matching with XPath 1.0
What you can do is to use `or` case, like:

```
//*[name()='item' or name()='Item' or name()='ITEM']
```

Comment: is there any way to implement these XPath 1.0 ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: There may be something different tag name such as `entry`, `product` etc. and it can be `itEm`.

Comment: Well, `entry` or `product` is not the case of case-insensitive `item`... So, you can and should use the `or` case as mentioned in the UPD section and just mention all these options explicitly

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0 you can use e.g. `//*[translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'item']` but as I said in a comment, consider to preprocess the XML in a transformation step to normalize the case of letters before using normal XPath selectors like `//item` in the second step.

Comment: another problem comes up at this time. When I execude this line it works fine `doc.xpath("/rss/channel/*[translate(local-name(), \"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\", \"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\") = 'item']")`. But when replace `/rss/channel/` to `//`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps raise that as a separate question with all the details or edit the question and show the details there.